# How to install JDK in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, jdk

I am unable to install JDK on Linux Mint.

I tried the following:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-lib
```

with the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package openjdk-7-jdk
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @A.B. In Linux Mint, there is nothing in this file usually.

Comment: Please post `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [WebUpd8 repository](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java):

First upgrade your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And if there is no problem, you may add this repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

This will also add JAVA_HOME to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about this problem, but it looks like your dependencies are broken or your package list is outdated.

1) So, try to update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2) And check your dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

3) If there are some broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

4) Get back to steps 1) and 2)

If it still doesn't work, try to find and install the package from Synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Listing your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder would be of help here.

To check if your current repository is updated with the package you want to install, run `apt-cache search openjdk-7-jdk` if you don't see any listing, you have an obsolete repository on your machine.

Option A: Get the relevant repository for `openjdk` and add it in your `sources.list` or better create new file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Option B: Try to install the Oracle java, it's more stable and has more support that `openjdk`

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry about installing through apt. Just download the JDK package [directly from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and dowload the script from

NO LONGER VALID LINK: http://1drv.ms/1woCbS5

and paste it into text editor and save it as `.sh` file. Then you should make the file executable by `chmod 755 filename.sh`. If you have any doubts please comment.

I got this code from https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre.

But since it contained JDK 7, I made it to JDK8. Make sure you delete `/usr/lib/jvm` folder by using `rm -rf jvm-folder-path`.

Comment: Please check your spelling, grammar, punctuation before posting here.

Comment: And don't provide links that may expire.